# Does typedef-ing a template type instantiate it?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

If I use `typedef` to rename a specialization of a template class (or struct), will that instantiate the template of that type in the assembly codegen? For example:

```
template<class T> struct Key
{
    float _time = 0.0f;
    T _value = T();
};
typedef Key<glm::vec3> VectorKey;
typedef Key<glm::quat> QuatKey;
```

Will this create the `Key<glm::vec3>` and `Key<glm::quat>` structs in my file so that I now have (essentially)

```
template<class T> struct Key
{
    float _time = 0.0f;
    T _value = T();
};
struct VectorKey
{
    float _time = 0.0f;
    glm::vec3 _value = glm::vec3();
};
struct QuatKey
{
    float _time = 0.0f;
    glm::quat _value = glm::quat();
};
```

I'm wondering if it's a bad idea to include a `typedef` in the header because if this happened, any files that included this header would then have more code included that is unnecessary.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "instantiate".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, typedefs are purely syntactical. Templates are only instantiated when actually used.

As per the C++14 standard (well, [the November draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) because I can't link directly to the ISO spec) (emphasis mine)

> 7.1.3 The `typedef` specifier
>   [...]
>   A name declared with the `typedef` specifier becomes a *typedef-name*. Within the scope of its declaration, a *typedef-name* is syntactically equivalent to a keyword and names the type associated with the identifier in the way described in Clause 8. A *typedef-name* is thus a synonym for another type. **A *typedef-name* does not introduce a new type the way a class declaration (9.1) or enum declaration does**.

Whereas the term "instantiating a template" is the same thing as "introducing a new type".

Imagine that during compilation that each new class/type definition encountered adds it to a "list-of-types". Whenever a template is encountered it is not added to the "list-of-types" until instantiated.

Comment: This surprises me. Do you have a reference to the standard?

Comment: I don't have a standard reference, but [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f72c2702aba4283) wouldn't compile if the typedefs caused instantiation.

Comment: @melpomene I've added a reference to my answer.

Comment: @Dai I'm not sure that's the right reference. The highlighted part only says that after `typedef A B`, `B` is merely another name for `A`, not a distinct type. It doesn't say how "real" `A` has to be.

Comment: @melpomene what do you mean by a type's "real"ness?

Comment: @Dai For example, if it's a templated type, whether the template has to be instantiated.

Comment: @melpomene That's what "introducing a new type" means. And a `typdef` does not do that. The specification clearly states this.

Comment: I don't think that's what "introducing a new type" means. Even if `typedef` forced template instantiation, `template Foo<T> X` wouldn't make `X` a new type. It would still be an alias for `Foo<T>`.